# Delete Registry key denied

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I would like to create a .cmd file to delete a specific key within registry key 'Run'

I tried to run this codeline but it doesn't work

```
REG DELETE HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Adobe Creative Cloud /f
```

Comment: Put keys containing spaces in double quotes  `REG DELETE "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Adobe Creative Cloud" /f`

Comment: It doesn't work, I have pasted this codeline in a .cmd file doesn't do its work reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\Adobe Creative Cloud" /f

Comment: There may be a permissions issue attached to they key. You will have to modify the permissions on the Adobe key using regedit.

Comment: Is there any error message? If there is an "access is denied" error, we can refer to this case: https://superuser.com/questions/489679/reg-delete-gives-me-access-is-denied-but-regedit-delete-is-ok

Answer (score 0):

After years of searching for a way to easily delete registry entries - I discovered RegScanner.

RegScanner by NirSoft is a small free utility that allows you to scan the Registry, find the desired Registry values that match to the specified search criteria, and display them in one list.

One of the best features of RegScanner is the ability to search for a keyword or value and create a REG file from the resulting list.

This comes in handy when you have multiple registry entries that refuse to delete. Many stubborn registry entries will delete when you create a REG file and replace all [HKEY values with [-HKEY before executing